# Predicting values for 95% CI graph - code errors

Tags: r, glm, predict

I'm trying to generate graphs of predicted values from GLMs, with 95% confidence intervals. I've been adapting some code from my supervisor, and it worked once, so I could then go on to produce the graph below. However, since then the code has stopped working. Even in the same project where nothing about the data frames has changed, it now just gives an error message.
Why is it doing this now and how can I fix it?

```
#Reordering factor levels for the models
river$SpeciesF<-river$Species
river$SpeciesF<-as.factor(river$SpeciesF)
river$SpeciesF<-relevel(river$SpeciesF,"UP")
View(river)
print(levels(river$SpeciesF))
#Models
massvlength<-glm(river$Mass~river$Length*river$SpeciesF,family=gaussian())
shellvlength<-glm(river$Log.shell~river$Log.length*river$SpeciesF,family=gaussian())
massvshell<-glm(river$Log.mass~river$Log.shell*river$SpeciesF,family=gaussian())

#Predicting values for massvlength model
pframe <- with(river,expand.grid(Length=seq(min(Length),max(Length),length=100), SpeciesF=levels(SpeciesF)))
pd7 <- cbind(pframe, predict(massvlength,newdata=pframe,type="response", se.fit = TRUE)[1:2])
pd7 <- transform(pd7, Fitted = fit, Upper = fit + (1.96 * se.fit), Lower = fit - (1.96 * se.fit))
```

This worked once - I know it worked because pd7 exists and I used it to plot a graph (linked below). I now need to use the code for the other two models but can't. It gives the error:

```
pd7.2 <- cbind(pframe2, predict(shellvlength,newdata=pframe2,type="response", se.fit = TRUE)[1:2])
```

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 300, 95
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 300 rows but variables found have 95 rows

Sorry, slightly new to this so not sure how I should add data to a post - 
Data:

```
dput(river)
structure(list(Species = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", 
"UP"), Mass = c(0.5117, 0.788, 0.722, 0.588, 1.58, 0.73, 0.784, 
0.3176, 0.4838, 0.5254, 0.737, 0.5622, 0.6244, 0.919, 0.961, 
0.91, 0.39, 0.37, 0.8, 0.37, 0.47, 0.51, 0.99, 0.56, 0.82, 1.755, 
2.906, 0.5928, 1.522, 1.793, 0.2909, 1.714, 2.272, 0.924, 2.49, 
0.804, 2.777, 1.788, 1.37, 1.07, 1.52, 1.51, 1.28, 2.59, 1.91, 
1.55, 0.81, 1.8, 1.03, 2.34, 1.37, 1.78, 0.95, 2.59, 1.03, 1.882, 
1.162, 1.294, 1.087, 1.206, 1.399, 1.112, 0.983, 1.511, 0.717, 
0.873, 1.189, 0.91, 1.123, 1.674, 2.365, 2.74, 1.47, 1.64, 0.96, 
1.12, 1.24, 1.49, 1.13, 1.46, 0.84, 1.12, 1.58, 0.96, 1.02, 0.91, 
1.2, 1.4, 1.82, 1.14, 1.43, 0.82, 0.89, 2.07, 2.08), Length = c(55.42, 
59.23, 56.69, 60.56, 74.69, 61.81, 74.47, 46.83, 53.58, 59.18, 
65.86, 60.47, 58.4, 62.44, 59.01, 72.9, 59.61, 54.17, 69.68, 
50.55, 57.37, 53.63, 75.84, 61.39, 64.26, 93.82, 105.79, 70.43, 
92.2, 83.49, 56.36, 106.66, 97.73, 81.09, 100.34, 77.39, 114.36, 
98.63, 93.61, 84.09, 95.75, 91.4, 87.88, 115.41, 109.77, 93.52, 
78.2, 95.7, 79.73, 102.7, 91.37, 101.74, 73.64, 108.02, 87.11, 
80.15, 82.09, 73.66, 65.66, 64.1, 78.47, 63.91, 62.87, 74.88, 
56.63, 55.81, 73.97, 62.68, 69.8, 90.08, 85.91, 97.02, 76.69, 
79.49, 67.22, 69.1, 66.71, 74.88, 68.32, 77.15, 64.54, 67.3, 
77.22, 61.48, 64.14, 70.32, 75.64, 80.19, 92.69, 71.29, 71.86, 
59.36, 64.09, 87.87, 79.53), Width = c(17.36, 18.59, 19.3, 19.51, 
26.31, 20.71, 25.07, 14.1, 16.37, 21.42, 21.97, 17.73, 20.41, 
20.92, 20.51, 23.85, 17.55, 16.67, 23.34, 14.59, 17.64, 18.62, 
24.6, 19.85, 19.87, 27.18, 32.2, 17.99, 24.79, 25.96, 13.53, 
34.76, 28.99, 24.39, 27.77, 20.01, 34.49, 33.42, 26.04, 24.18, 
28, 26.3, 23.94, 33.8, 33.37, 26.47, 21.72, 27.77, 20.77, 30.01, 
27.89, 30.8, 20.45, 32.16, 22.7, 26.17, 24.87, 21.59, 22.16, 
22.66, 26.61, 19.31, 22.15, 23.42, 19.03, 17.75, 23.68, 18.32, 
21.08, 30.52, 26.47, 27.76, 24.63, 25.98, 19.96, 23.2, 21.2, 
23.03, 21.74, 21.82, 18.83, 21.55, 22.35, 18.51, 19.95, 22.31, 
21.76, 25.21, 28.28, 20.94, 22.49, 19.52, 20.34, 29.12, 26.63
), Height = c(34.02, 35.22, 35.94, 35.95, 43.32, 36.68, 41.85, 
29.98, 30.45, 33.08, 37.42, 38.55, 34.3, 37.61, 39.56, 41.06, 
35.13, 32.38, 43.8, 32.74, 35.44, 33.77, 43.52, 35.47, 38.17, 
53.47, 59.19, 40.84, 55.06, 49.6, 32.72, 58.04, 56.39, 45.01, 
55.64, 43.65, 64.48, 53.25, 50.66, 47.47, 53.14, 53.6, 51.86, 
65.52, 58.58, 51.74, 44.37, 49.88, 45.82, 58.78, 48.61, 59.25, 
40.99, 56.79, 48.47, 34.83, 36.78, 33.66, 31.63, 30.76, 34.77, 
28.83, 30.19, 32.78, 28.1, 25.35, 32.75, 29.71, 29.85, 42.24, 
39.9, 43.25, 35.82, 38.47, 30.69, 33.7, 30.38, 32.37, 31.72, 
34.15, 31.27, 30.05, 34.7, 28.39, 29.07, 31.49, 34.01, 34.58, 
40.15, 30.76, 32.74, 28.18, 28.72, 39.87, 37.76), Shell = c(2.56, 
4.21, 2.93, 4.63, 7.16, 4.62, 8.26, 1.7, 2.49, 4.2, 4.85, 3.3, 
3.82, 4.41, 3.41, 6.6, 4.11, 2.74, 8.23, 1.89, 2.87, 3.04, 9.21, 
3.87, 5.38, 8.65, 14.99, 3.76, 9.17, 7.51, 1.79, 17.29, 9.2, 
6.45, 10.97, 5.07, 18.35, 14.16, 8.52, 6.4, 12.65, 7.77, 7.09, 
24.59, 14.55, 7.43, 4.6, 9.88, 4.88, 15.64, 8.75, 13.08, 4.67, 
13.23, 5.82, 18.61, 15.06, 9.99, 9.87, 10.34, 13.46, 7.23, 8.99, 
10.46, 6.15, 5.56, 10.7, 5.73, 8.79, 26.88, 20.04, 17.2, 12.52, 
18.8, 9.28, 11.45, 9.16, 10.12, 11.52, 14.4, 9.92, 7.82, 11.79, 
6.62, 8.7, 11.88, 11.02, 16.5, 22.17, 8.26, 12.4, 7.36, 7.39, 
19.04, 17.3), Log.mass = c(-0.290984583027883, -0.103473782510445, 
-0.141462802430361, -0.230622673923862, 0.198657086954423, -0.136677139879544, 
-0.105683937315562, -0.498119506244941, -0.315334135974139, -0.279509931549949, 
-0.132532512140949, -0.250109158728578, -0.20453710560962, -0.0366844886138888, 
-0.0172766123314546, -0.0409586076789064, -0.408935392973501, 
-0.431798275933005, -0.0969100130080564, -0.431798275933005, 
-0.327902142064283, -0.292429823902064, -0.00436480540245004, 
-0.2518119729938, -0.0861861476162833, 0.244277120801843, 0.463295609962003, 
-0.227091805028728, 0.182414652434554, 0.253580289562183, -0.536256278752941, 
0.234010817587179, 0.356408327038981, -0.0343280287798933, 0.396199347095736, 
-0.0947439512515487, 0.443575879750258, 0.252367514459899, 0.136720567156407, 
0.0293837776852096, 0.181843587944773, 0.17897694729317, 0.107209969647868, 
0.413299764081252, 0.281033367247728, 0.190331698170291, -0.0915149811213503, 
0.255272505103306, 0.0128372247051722, 0.369215857410143, 0.136720567156407, 
0.250420002308894, -0.0222763947111523, 0.413299764081252, 0.0128372247051721, 
0.274619619091238, 0.0652061280543119, 0.111934276332682, 0.0362295440862946, 
0.0813473078041325, 0.145817714491828, 0.0461047872460386, -0.00744648216786434, 
0.179264464339025, -0.1444808443322, -0.0589857562944303, 0.0751818546186916, 
-0.0409586076789063, 0.0503797562614578, 0.223755453657241, 0.37383114507383, 
0.437750562820388, 0.167317334748176, 0.214843848047698, -0.0177287669604316, 
0.0492180226701817, 0.0934216851622351, 0.173186268412274, 0.0530784434834197, 
0.164352855784437, -0.0757207139381184, 0.0492180226701817, 0.198657086954423, 
-0.0177287669604316, 0.00860017176191757, -0.0409586076789064, 
0.0791812460476248, 0.146128035678238, 0.260071387985075, 0.0569048513364726, 
0.155336037465062, -0.0861861476162833, -0.0506099933550873, 
0.315970345456918, 0.318063334962762), Log.shell = c(0.40823996531185, 
0.624282095835668, 0.46686762035411, 0.665580991017953, 0.854913022307856, 
0.664641975556125, 0.916980047320382, 0.230448921378274, 0.396199347095736, 
0.6232492903979, 0.685741738602264, 0.518513939877887, 0.582063362911709, 
0.644438589467838, 0.532754378992498, 0.819543935541869, 0.613841821876069, 
0.437750562820388, 0.91539983521227, 0.276461804173244, 0.457881896733992, 
0.482873583608754, 0.964259630196849, 0.587710965018911, 0.730782275666389, 
0.937016107464814, 1.17580163284828, 0.575187844927661, 0.962369335670021, 
0.875639937004168, 0.252853030979893, 1.23779499327392, 0.963787827345555, 
0.809559714635268, 1.04020662757471, 0.705007959333336, 1.26363606858811, 
1.15106325335375, 0.9304395947667, 0.806179973983887, 1.10209052551184, 
0.890421018800914, 0.850646235183066, 1.39075852873872, 1.16286299332193, 
0.870988813760575, 0.662757831681574, 0.994756944587628, 0.688419822002711, 
1.19423674872383, 0.942008053022313, 1.11660774398825, 0.669316880566112, 
1.1215598441875, 0.764922984649889, 1.26974637313077, 1.17782497186468, 
0.999565488225982, 0.994317152669637, 1.01452053875792, 1.12904505988796, 
0.859138297294531, 0.953759691733229, 1.01953168453126, 0.788875115775417, 
0.745074791582057, 1.02938377768521, 0.75815462196739, 0.943988875073772, 
1.42942926438179, 1.30189771719521, 1.23552844690755, 1.09760432887441, 
1.27415784926368, 0.967547976218862, 1.05880548667591, 0.96189547366785, 
1.00518051250378, 1.06145247908719, 1.15836249209525, 0.996511672154179, 
0.893206753059848, 1.07151380509509, 0.8208579894397, 0.939519252618618, 
1.07481644064517, 1.04218159451577, 1.21748394421391, 1.34576569311449, 
0.916980047320382, 1.09342168516224, 0.866877814337499, 0.868644438394826, 
1.27966694404846, 1.2380461031288), Log.length = c(1.74366652144621, 
1.77254173264094, 1.75350645699097, 1.78218586649202, 1.87326245943873, 
1.79105874359183, 1.87198135384337, 1.67052415778208, 1.72900270927219, 
1.77217496082461, 1.81862172637589, 1.78153996860594, 1.7664128471124, 
1.79546289439038, 1.770925614639, 1.86272752831797, 1.77531912182948, 
1.7337588355872, 1.84310814199961, 1.70372115992702, 1.75868484988244, 
1.72940779696307, 1.87989832433001, 1.7880976333803, 1.8079407212155, 
1.97229542861114, 2.02444461713135, 1.84775768839233, 1.96473092105363, 
1.92163446105371, 1.75097098443732, 2.02800157934686, 1.99002789877029, 
1.90896730041839, 2.00147409669173, 1.8886848466597, 2.05827414668595, 
1.99400903312361, 1.97132224524281, 1.92474435247995, 1.98113878264066, 
1.96094619573383, 1.94389004824847, 2.06224344102648, 2.04048366420627, 
1.97090449815378, 1.89320675305985, 1.98091193777684, 1.90162176409336, 
2.01157044359728, 1.96080362491177, 2.00749173329534, 1.86711377983198, 
2.03350417294517, 1.94006801373935, 1.90390352669016, 1.91429025566595, 
1.86723171451889, 1.81730087839332, 1.80685802951882, 1.89470365260923, 
1.80556881754856, 1.79844346035019, 1.87436583573005, 1.75304656162653, 
1.74671202251666, 1.86905561870191, 1.79712898779655, 1.84385542262316, 
1.95462837750727, 1.93404371903553, 1.98686127029004, 1.88473873776963, 
1.90031249698373, 1.82749850813346, 1.8394780473742, 1.82419094065258, 
1.87436583573005, 1.83454785768095, 1.88733593039917, 1.80982896106789, 
1.82801506422398, 1.88772979728803, 1.78873385882771, 1.80712895559242, 
1.84707886206572, 1.878751520173, 1.9041202134762, 1.9670328821587, 
1.85302861471299, 1.85648721286863, 1.77349389227097, 1.80679027158407, 
1.94384062640126, 1.90053098245276), SpeciesF = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("UP", 
"AA", "AC"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Species", "Mass", 
"Length", "Width", "Height", "Shell", "Log.mass", "Log.shell", 
"Log.length", "SpeciesF"), row.names = c(NA, -95L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in the help file for `predict.glm`:

> Variables are first looked for in newdata and then searched for in the
>   usual way (which will include the environment of the formula used in
>   the fit). A warning will be given if the variables found are not of
>   the same length as those in newdata if it was supplied.

This means that the error you are getting is because your newdata is missing a variable, and predict is trying to use the variable from the original data which is of a different length. So `pframe2` is likely missing a variable from the specification of the model you are using.

As an aside, since you are only doing a linear model anyway, why not just use `lm` and get `predict.lm` to compute the CIs for you using `interval="confidence"`?

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about changing that? I don't have the best knowledge of r so I'm afraid I don't fully understand what role newdata/pframe is playing - as I said, the code is adapted.

Comment: `newdata` should be a data.frame of new variables to make predictions on. You need to have all of the predictor variables in it. So for the shellvlength model you need Log.shell, Log.length and SpeciesF.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this works but for anyone else with a similar issue - as soon as I changed the model formula from

massvlength<-glm(river$Mass~river$Length*river$SpeciesF,family=gaussian())

To

massvlength<-glm(Mass~Length*SpeciesF,family=gaussian(),data=river)

It worked perfectly - even though pframe etc. was unchanged.